# Set absolute working directory for OS X

Tags: install4j

I am currently building an OS X installer with Install4j for my Java program. I try to set the working directory for the executable. You can choose the working directory under "Launchers". Unfortunately, you can only specify directories relative to the executable.

Is it possible to specify an absolute working directory, such as `/$USER_HOME/Library/Preferences`?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify environment variables with the syntax `${VARIABLE}`, so `${HOME}/Library/Preferences` should work.

To have different values for different platforms, use a compiler variable and override its value under "Customize project defaults->Compiler variables" in the media wizards.